# Jekyll recursive dynamic include via parameter

Tags: include, jekyll, github-pages

On my blog that is powered by GitHub Pages, I'm trying to make it easy to include code snippets in my blog posts. For this, I have created *code-snippet.html* in the *_includes*-directory:

```
<pre><code>{% include {{include.file}} %}</code></pre>
```

To include a code snippet in a blog post, I use the following code:

```
Code snippet: {% include code-snippet.html file="snippets/MyPost/MySnippet.cs" %}
```

However, the content of the file *_includes/snippets/MyPost/MySnippet.cs* does not get included. If I output `{{include.file}}` in *code-snippet.html* I can see that the parameter is passed in correctly, but if I try to include it, I get nothing.

Comment: I assume that such recursion is not supported. But if code-snippet.html ONLY contains the pre and code tags, you can easily add them manually, thus avoiding one extra level of inclusion. I personally prefer to cut and paste code into the main text (I use Textile, most people prefer Markdown) and surround it with `{% highlight %}` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question. Here is my two cents.

Here, I took the example of your `_posts/2012-11-16-idisposable.html` post.

#### Storing code snippets

As code is part of the post's content I logically move it to the `_posts` folder. Storing it in the `_includes` folder is not so good as this is a template folder.

Let's copy the `idisposable/TryFinallyDispose.cs.html` from `_includes/code-snippets` to `_posts/_code` or anything you want.

As the code is stored in an underscored folder (_code), it will not be processed *as is* by Jekyll. We will just 'include' it in our posts.

Note : code snippet can be saved as `code.cs`

As we will use highligting from Jekyll dependancies (see below), we just rework code snippet by, removing `<pre>` and `<code>`.

It becomes :

```
var x = new X(); // X is a class that implements IDisposable
try
{
  // do something with x
}
finally
{
  x.Dispose();
}
```

#### Displaying code

Jekyll offers various ways to highlight code (`markdown`, [`pygments`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting), `rouge`, ..). Here I demonstrate the `pygments` way, but it's up to you to explore other solutions.

The base template will be (`_includes/code-snippet-csharp.html`):

```
{% capture filePath %}_code/{{include.file}}{% endcapture %}
{% highlight csharp %}
{% include_relative {{filePath}} %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

**note**: one drawback here, in the `{% highlight csharp %}`, code name is hardcoded. I found no way to pass the `language` to the `highlight` tag as a variable. If you want to use multiple languages, you'll need to duplicate the include template as `code-snippet-csharp.html`, `code-snippet-js.html`, ...

#### Styling code

In order to beautify our code, we need an extra css file. [The basic one is here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mojombo/tpw/master/css/syntax.css), but there is [many more](https://www.google.fr/search?q=pygments%20css).

Style is saved as `assets/syntax.css` and included in `_layouts/default.hmtl` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseUrl}}assets/syntax.css">
```

And it can also be included in your sass process.

#### Including code in posts

We now just have to call our code in `_posts/2012-11-16-idisposable.html`.

```
{% include code-snippets/idisposable/TryFinallyDispose.cs.html %}
```

Is replaced by :

```
{% include code-snippet-csharp.html file="idisposable/TryFinallyDispose.cs.html" %}
```

#### Result

Better content structure and a nicely highlighted code !

Comment: Great detailed answer. I'm not using the built-in syntax highlighters yet, but the general idea of your answer helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Alstublieft ! Anyway, I like sure this css can spice up you code snippets : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nicolashery/5765395/raw/91ae32653fec817d26ba322cbe9d62192b07b851/solarized-dark.css

Answer (score 0):

You can [include code](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/545d8991/_posts/2012-03-22-notepad2-mod.md) like this

```
~~~
{% include snippets/MyPost/MySnippet.cs %}
~~~
```

Comment: I actually prefer to work in HTML for my blog, because it gives me better control. And the reason I want to use a separate *code-snippet.html* is not just because of the `<pre><code>`, but also because I want to automatically escape the `< > &` later. Currently, the snippets are escaped manually.

Comment: First of all, because GitHub Pages uses Jekyll. And because it's a pretty good static site generator (especially for blogs), whether you're using HTML or Markdown.

Comment: How do you do (static) includes in HTML? How do you automatically generate overview pages for blog posts, an RSS-feed, links to next/previous post in HTML? How do you do layouts (that are used by each page and post) in HTML?